# Enable VT support for intel haxm on Hyper-V vm (Windows 10 Pro)?

Tags: windows, intel, hyper-v, haxm

Objective: To enable intel haxm on Guest OS (win 10 pro), for increasing the speed of Android emulator 10x then default visual studio emulator.

More on intelhaxm [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Issue:

When I check for pre-requisites for enabling haxm, the haxm_check.exe output says "VT support -- no"

Questions:

1. How to enable "VT support" on Hyper-V machine with Windows 10 Pro on it?
2. Is there a way to add delay during boot process and press some key to get into BIOS settings of Guest OS (WIndows 10 Pro)?

Here is Host setup:
    Host machine: Windows 10 Pro 
    Virtualization in BIOS: Enabled
    Hyper-V windows feature: Turned ON.

Here is Guest VM setup:
    VM created with Hyper-V
    Guest OS: Windows 10 Pro
    Hyper-V windows feature: Turned OFF.

Comment: You could try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization).  I don't know whether Hyper-V's virtualization extensions are compatible with HAXM, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this setup will not work. Intel HAXM has to run directly on the physical hardware and not as a guest. Moreover, if you have both technologies on the same hardware, Hyper-V and Intel HAXM can not co-exist at the same. See:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-windows

Even with the upcoming nested- virtualization support in Microsoft Windows, HAXM will not work in it's current state because it is based on QEMU (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/emu-master-dev/README) and not Hyper-V. The entire Android Emulator kernel and virtualization stack would have be re-written with Hyper-V in order to work in a nested scenario.